# Using Route 53, how to point a domain without www to an ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-elastic-ip

I can already CNAME the www to my ELB DNS, but how would I route the non www as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily through the control panel.  Go to the 'a' record editing screen (panel on the right when you select a record in route53) and select Yes for alias.  Click in the text box and your Load Balancer's target will appear.  Select it, and save.